# Removing redundant code from http server, filehandler

Tags: java, http, handler

I have set up my webserver, for the time being only localhost, at port 8080 for testing.

```
public class WebServer {

static int port = 8080; //not the final port
static String ip = "127.0.0.1"; // not the final IP


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    InetSocketAddress i = new InetSocketAddress(ip, port); //localhost - 127.0.0.1
    HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(i, 0);

    server.createContext("/tester", new testHandler("index.html"));

    server.createContext("/startpage", new PagesHandler());
    server.createContext("/online", new OnlineHandler());
    server.createContext("/logfile", new LogFileHandler());

    server.setExecutor(null);
    server.start();

}
```

I have a seperate handler for each of the page references, which basicly does the same thing.
Example for the PagesHandler()

```
   static class PagesHandler implements HttpHandler {

    String content = "public/";

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange he) throws IOException {

        File file = new File(content + "index.html");

        byte[] bytesToSend = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        try {
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            bis.read(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.length);
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
        he.sendResponseHeaders(200, bytesToSend.length);
        try (OutputStream os = he.getResponseBody()) {
            os.write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.length);
        }

    }

}
```

This makes me have a lot of redundant code, which i really dont see the need for.
My question is. I am guessing there is a way to parse the handler with a filename, instead of the hardcodeded filename in File file,

But how would i go about doing that?
would a constructor of the handler with a String parameter for the filename do?
like so

```
public pagesHandler(String fileName){
}
```

and in the main something like this:

```
 server.createContext("/tester", new testHandler("index.html"));
```

And if not how would i go about reducing the rudandant code ?

Comment: Yes. That is how you could do it.

Comment: alright, however in my testing of this, i cant seem to get a hold of the index.html file i am trying to fetch. i am getting a null pointer exception?

Comment: editited - not a null pointer exception but a filenotfound exception, since the fileName is null.

java.io.FileNotFoundException: public/null (No such file or   directory)